# Type for params for a navigate function

Tags: typescript, react-navigation, react-typescript, javascript-intellisense

Hi can anyone help me on this Typescript, recently moved to it, try reading documents and chatGPT for it but still have some problems.

Thing is I have two enums that contains screen key

```
export enum OnboardFlowScreens {
  ONBOARDING = "Onboarding",
  WELCOME = "Welcome",
}

export enum AuthFlowScreens {
  SIGNUP = "SignUp",
  LOGIN = "Login",
}

type BaseParamList = {
  [K in ScreenName]: any;
};

export interface OnboardFlowParamList extends AbstractParamList {
  [OnboardFlowScreens.ONBOARDING]: undefined;
  [OnboardFlowScreens.WELCOME]: { user: string };
}

export interface AuthFlowParamList extends AbstractParamList {
  [AuthFlowScreens.SIGNUP]: { user: string };
  [AuthFlowScreens.LOGIN]: { usrLogin: string };
}

type Merge<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};

export interface AnyParamList
  extends Merge<
    OnboardFlowParamList &
      AuthFlowParamList
  > {}
```

I tried to create a custom navigate function, i'm not using the default one from react-navigation

```
const navigate = <T extends keyof AnyParamList>(
  screen: T,
  params?: AnyParamList[T]
): void => {
  const props = [screen, params] as never;
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(...props);
};
```

When I use this navigate function like below for example, the type for it is
**const navigate: <OnboardFlowScreens.WELCOME>(screen: OnboardFlowScreens.WELCOME, params: any) => void**
How can I change **params: any** to **params: {user: 'string'}** at here, or exactly AnyParamList[screen] as I defined

```
navigate(OnboardFlowScreens.ONBOARDING, "a"); should be invalid here
```

Answer (score -2):

Made it working through update BaseParamList

```
type BaseParamList = {
  [K in ScreenName]: {} | undefined;
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).